# React Router 4. Get active route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have code

router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from "react-dom";
import history from './history';
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router'

import Main from "./main/component";
import Profile from "./profile/component";
import TextStatus from "./textstatus/component";
import ContactList from "./contactlist/component";

render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <Main>
      <Route
        path="/:user_name"
        component={Profile}
        component_id="Profile"
      />
      <Route
        path="/:user_name/status"
        component={TextStatus}
        component_id="TextStatus"
      />
      <Route
        path="/:user_name/contacts"
        component={ContactList}
        component_id="ContactList"
      />
    </Main>
  </Router>

), document.getElementById("main"));
```

history.js

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

main/component.js //main layout

```
import React from 'react';
class Main extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (this.props.children)
   }
}
```

How can I get the current route (component_id) in Main component?

In react router 1.0.3 I did this: `this.props.children.props.route.component_id`

Thank you for attention!

Comment: First, why do you need the prop component_id? Considering that you are already rendering the right component. I think the way you are doing isn't how things work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update for React v16.8+ & React Router v5+**:

Use `useLocation` hook.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Main = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  console.log(location.pathname); // outputs currently active route
  return children;
};

export default Main;
```

Wrap your components with `withRouter` and then you can access the current active route using `this.props.location.pathname`.

Eg:

```
import React from 'react';
class Main extends React.Component {
   render() {
      console.log(this.props.location.pathname); // outputs currently active route
      return (this.props.children)
   }
}
export default withRouter(Main);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your Main component with [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) HOC in-order to get the location props from the context.